# Powershell LDAP Query get list of all Groups and their owners

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, ldap-query

I am lost I need to write a query to give me all the groups that a user is the owner of in a CSV format. An alternative would be a list of all groups with their username and e-mail.

The CSV format should either be:

```
"GroupName", ,"givenname","surname","office","mail",
```

or (preferred)

```
"givenname","surname","office","mail","group1","group2","group3",etc...
```

I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
$test = 'OU=Practice Office,DC=us,DC=LMCorp,DC=com'
$test | ForEach {
    Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties ManagedBy -SearchBase $_
} | Select Name, ManagedBy,objectGUID,memberOf,givenname,surname,office,mail,‌​title,telephoneNumbe‌​r,department | Sort -Property Name | Out-File C:\temp\1.csv
```

Comment: I have tried this with no luck   $test = 'OU=Practice Office,DC=us,DC=LMCorp,DC=com'
$test | ForEach {Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties ManagedBy -SearchBase $_ } |
 Select Name, ManagedBy,objectGUID,memberOf,givenname,surname,office,mail,title,telephoneNumber,department  |
 Sort -Property Name |
 Out-File  C:\temp\1.csv

Comment: Please [edit] your question. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: Is that LDAP string for the OU actually correct? You could skip the `ForEach` as you're only using `$test` anyway. That actually should get you a CSV as in your first format if you replace `Out-File` by `Export-Csv`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why your using a foreach. Wouldn't this work?

```
$test = ou location
$groups = get-adgroup -searchbase $test -properties ManagedBy
```

Then $groups will contain what you're looking for. Check its contents by just entering it at the PowerShell prompt:

```
$groups
```

Or

```
$groups[0]
```

Will give you the first element in the set. Then you can sort and pipe out to a file. Can you get that far, that you're getting the right AD objects returned?

Comment: not quite understanding, I am super new can you post a code sample for me to see?

Comment: But he gave you the full example. The lines starting with `$test` (obviously you would have to add the LDAP string yourself and `$groups` can be used as is. Assuming you have the RSAT tools (for the AD PowerShell module) installed. You might have to do a `Import-Module ActiveDirectory` beforehand.